# android service to show push notification on launch of an application

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want to start a service which will run at the background all the time and when an user launches any application it should show a push notification with the name of the application. How can I do this?

Comment: Do it via android AlamManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

push notification is pushing by server, so you have to create notification in client side.